# How do I add exemptions for HTTPS redirection in Startup.cs? (ASP.NET Core 2.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In my Startup.cs Configure method, I'm calling app.UseHsts() and app.UseHttpsRedirection(). When using Let's Encrypt, I need to serve extensionless files in the .well-known folder over HTTP.

What's the best way to add an exemption for HTTPS when serving files from .well-known?

Here's my configure method in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseWellKnownFolderForLetsEncrypt(env);
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Also here's the extension method serving static content out of the well-known folder.

```
public static class LetsEncryptAppBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseWellKnownFolderForLetsEncrypt(this IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var wellKnownFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, ".well-known")).FullName;

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(wellKnownFolder),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true // serve extensionless file
        });

        return app;
    }
}
```

Comment: HSTS, in particular, instructs the client to *never* accept communication over anything but HTTPS. That's kind of the whole point: preventing insecure redirection. As a result, there's no way to add an "exemption", as doing so would defeat the entire point of it. Why do you want to serve anything over HTTP anyways? Even if the resource doesn't need to be secure, it's not going to hurt for it to be.

Comment: This is for the HTTP challenge that let's encrypt uses. Let's encrypt is the certificate authority which gives me the certificate to use for HTTPS. I was thinking this was a chicken-egg problem. Having a read though, it looks like it will still work with HTTPS redirection using a self-signed certificate so I think I don't actually need it.

I appreciate the comment, thanks :)